# Showing context variable within HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

What I am trying to do is to populate a html table with the same numbers of rows as entries in my dictionary.
I am passing my dictionary items as a context variable to the html.
I can show my dictionary items as follows:

```
{% for key,value in top_items.items %}
<ul>{{ key }}</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

But when I try an stick it into a table to create table rows, like below, it does not work. It seems to put them all in one row. Instead of making a new row for each item.

```
    <table class="u-half-width">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        {% for key,value in top_items.items %}
        <tr>{{ key }}</tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What templating system is this? It looks like Liquid to me...

Comment: chartsjs is the boilerplate

Comment: ChartJS is a charting library, not a HTML templating library. Where and how are you seeing this?

Comment: ah i am using django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid; you can't nest a `<tr>` inside another `<tr>`, and you don't have any `<td>`/`<th>` elements.

Try:

```
<tbody>
    {% for key,value in top_items.items %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ key }}</th>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```